# How to groupby with the criteria that groups' set union is not the empty set?

Tags: pandas, set, union

I have the following dataframe

```
df_testing = pd.DataFrame({
    'Q': ['Q_0', 'Q_1', 'Q_2', 'Q_3', 'Q_4', 'Q_5', 'Q_5', 'Q_6', 'Q_7', 'Q_7', 'Q_8'],
    'A': ['A_0', 'A_1', 'A_1', 'A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'A_5', 'A_5', 'A_6', 'A_7']
})


      Q       A
0   Q_0     A_0
1   Q_1     A_1
2   Q_2     A_1
3   Q_3     A_1
4   Q_4     A_2
5   Q_5     A_3
6   Q_5     A_4
7   Q_6     A_5
8   Q_7     A_5
9   Q_7     A_6
10  Q_8     A_7
```

and after grouping by Q's:

```
# As with same Qs
as_with_same_qs = df_testing.groupby('Q', as_index=False).agg({'A': tuple})

    Q         A
0   Q_0     (A_0,)
1   Q_1     (A_1,)
2   Q_2     (A_1,)
3   Q_3     (A_1,)
4   Q_4     (A_2,)
5   Q_5     (A_3, A_4)
6   Q_6     (A_5,)
7   Q_7     (A_5, A_6)
8   Q_8     (A_7,)
```

I need to group again, but this time by A. The problem is that by default, the `groupby` criteria is only that the values are the same. In this case, I would like to join into the same group the rows whose sets of A's have any element in common. For example, the rows:

```
6   Q_6     (A_5,)
7   Q_7     (A_5, A_6)
```

Have a common element, which is `A_5`, therefore `set.union((A_5,), (A_5, A_6)) != set()`. Because of that, I would like them to be grouped together and aggregate Q's as I liked afterwards. **The problem is that I do not know how to define this user-custom groupby function**.

Expected result:

```
A            Q
(A_0,)       (Q_0,)
(A_1,)       (Q_1, Q_2, Q_3)
(A_2,)       (Q_4,)
(A_3, A_4)   (Q_5,)
(A_5, A_6)   (Q_6, Q_7,)
(A_7,)       (Q_8,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[set(e).issubset(f) for f in as_with_same_qs.A] for e in as_with_same_qs.A])
b = [np.array(as_with_same_qs.A)[e] for e in a]
c = [np.argmax([len(f) for f in np.array(as_with_same_qs.A)[e]]) for e in a]
as_with_same_qs['A'] = [b[i][v] for i,v in enumerate(c)]
as_with_same_qs.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg({'Q': tuple})

    A           Q
0   (A_0,)      (Q_0,)
1   (A_1,)      (Q_1, Q_2, Q_3)
2   (A_2,)      (Q_4,)
3   (A_3, A_4)  (Q_5,)
4   (A_5, A_6)  (Q_6, Q_7)
5   (A_7,)      (Q_8,)
```

Comment: Thank you, this can definitely help. I would like to know if I could specify a custom-made function to the groupby in order to do this. In fact, a function that dynamically groups the rows (between them, and not in a pre-established way of grouping such as bins), in some sort of way like a reduce function does. This is, by establishing a comparison function between the items that the groupby analyses so I can just tell the groupby to group two items if (condition(x,y)) where x and y are the rows being compared. e.g. `groupby(lambda x, y: set.union(set(x), set(y)) != set())`